# Android Service and its engine

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have one doubt about using services. I have a service that initializes an object, is it a bad practice to pass an instance of the service to the object so it can be used for that object? A simplified object would be:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject(this);


    ...
}

public MyObject {
    private MyService myService;

    public MyObject(MyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    ...
    private void exampleMethod() {
        myService.method();
    }
}
```

What do you think? Is it a bad practice? How could I solve that issue without passing the service's instance?
The fact is that I want to split the code in two classes because the features are different, the websocket is connected from the service class, but the methods to parse/send events through the websocket are in the second class. I want to do this way in order to avoid having one class with 2000 lines of code, and by splitting the code by features. The service handles the websocket connection, while the other class handles the other features. As everything is asynchronous, the second class needs an instance of the service class. For instance: if an error is received and parsed (on the second class), this second class must call the service class to update its status and do a reconnection.

EDIT:
I'm thinking about implementing the following solution:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject() {
          protected void onSuccess() {
              ...
          }
    };


    ...
}

public abstract class MyObject {


    public MyObject() {
    }

    protected abstract void onSuccess();

    ...
    private void exampleMethod() {
        ...
        onSuccess()
    }
}
```

The more I think about it, the better solution I think it is. What do you think?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You may consider storing a WeakReference of your service in your object

Comment: the object lives in some one life circle. i suppose it is activity. your object can not start or stop you servece witout reference to activity. why you do that? i see you execute method in service for what?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The object is not an activity, is an engine that connects to a websocket, so when I get a response from that get socket (in MyObject) I must notify the service with the changes. But, as this is not an activity/fragment, I cannot bind to the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes no sense at all. I suggest you to use a interface if you need to pass a callback to a dao (the websocket controller). The thing is that you should use your service to implement your websocket controller.
 Please add the websocket code, so we can suggest more changes.

EDIT:

```
  public interface onGetData {

    public void onSuccess(Object response) // here you pass the obj type you need in your service

    public void onError(Object error) // same, but if things fail

  }



 public class MyService extends Service implements onGetData  {

    @Override
    public void OnCreate() {
       MyObject myObject = new MyObject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Object error) {
    }


 }


public MyObject {
  private OnGetData onGetData ;

  public MyObject(OnGetData onGetData) {
    this.onGetData = onGetData;
  }

  private void onRequestSuccess(Object response) {
    onGetData.onSuccess(response)
  }

  private void onRequestError(Object error) {
    onGetData.onError(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be added as comment.not answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited giving more information. The fact is that, as the second class parses and handles the responses from the web socket, if, for instance, there's an error, that second class must notify the service class in order to change the current status and do a reconnection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I don't understand what is the difference between passing the Service's instance and passing the interface's instance. However, thanks to your answer I've though about another solution which I think that could be better. I've edited my answer with that solution, what do you think? Thanks again

Comment: Yous solution has the same effect as using an interface but interfaces are made for that purpose, overriding a method in that way is a bad pratice as the way to go is create an interface. Services are complex classes that have its own lifecycle, thread and are managed internally by android, they shouldnt be used that way, maybe shit will happen, maybe not, but its wrong in an oop point of view. Interfaces are made just for that purpose, they do nothing but a bridge between classes, thats why you should be using them instead of trying to create your own solution for something already answered.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll take it into account. One question, what is the difference between creating an interface and passing the service object without an interface? Why just do: public MyObject(MyService myService){this.myService = myService} instead of onGetData? What about doing MyObject myObject = new MyObject(this); on initialization instead of onCreate method?

Comment: When you pass service as an interface, internally, java is converting your service to be just an interface inside the MyObject (its the same as doing String stringObject = MyModel.toString(); stringObject dont even know myModel exists, its just received a string as its values, it dont matter from where the string came). Every Android class has its own lifecycle. Maybe something you need will only be avaliable after the onCreate or onStart (thats when service is fully loaded and when the service goal should be implemented). Theres an onDestroy too, there is where you should stop your socket.